# Someone found out the password of an Ubuntu Server - is there an IP-Adress log or similar

Tags: ubuntu, logging, passwords

Seemingly someone has found out the password of an Ubuntuserver through the use of many passwordrequests, ist there an IP-address log or similar? I recommend to use only really sure passwords and always an other password. Many Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If the server was accessed over HTTP there's [*apache access log*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html), but if it was done over ssh I'm afraid it won't be logged anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I will watch into the Nginx log.